# Json request gives invalid lable while using ajax request

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying call my remote server to retrieve some json data . i tried the below code

```
$.ajax({
        url : url + "&callback=?",
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data.results.length);
        }
    });
```

if i use the twitter url it works for my remote server url firebug gives invalid lable .But is is an valid json.can any one tell me how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing in your data to the remote server via the DATA attribute:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: url,  
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    cache:false,                      
    success: function( data)
    {  
        success_callback( data);
    },  
    error: function( data)
    {
        error_callback( data);
    }
});
```

If you are trying to make an ajax call across servers (calling file on one server, receiving file on another server) then you will have to look into JSONP.